# Azure Function with output to ServiceBus receives binding error

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: X.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter
>   'outputQueue'.
>  System.Private.Uri: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter
>   name: uriString

The header on my class is as follows

```
[FunctionName("MyFunc")]
  public static async  Task<IAsyncCollector<string>> 
    Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
      HttpRequest req, ILogger log, 
      [ServiceBus("my_queue", EntityType.Queue,Connection = "SLQueueConnectionString")] 
      IAsyncCollector<string> outputQueue
    )
```

my local.settings.json

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME": "Production",
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~2",
        "ScmType": "None",
        "WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED": "False",
        "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "8.11.1",
        "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sil...",
        "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "sil...",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME": "Sil...",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sil...",
        "SLQueueConnectionString": "Endpoint = sb://sil..."
    }
}
```

Comment: I test in my site and it works well, could you show more details to help me reproduce the issue:)

Comment: I think it is because I was working with Core 3.0 preview.  It works fine in 2.2

Answer (score 0):

It was due to using a preview version.  Production version working.